# App behaves differently on different devices of the same model with same version of iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Two iPhone 4S with the same version of iOS running the same app experience differnt (and often mutually exclusive) bugs

I'm running into a strange (and extremely frustraing) problem where an app I am building behaves differently on different devices of the same model. I have no idea why. When I test the code I use both real devices(my iPhone 5, 4S , iPod touch, and iPad 2) and the simulator to help discover and fix bugs. However, what's happening is that when I send test builds out to other people with the same devices (e.g. another iPhone 4S), running the same iOS version they are reporting bugs that I cannot find or duplicate on my own device. I don't think these people are lying about their experience but is it really possible that two phones of the same model with the same iOS version can experience different bugs? If yes, how should I approach debugging this since I cannot duplicate the issue?

Comment: It would entirely depend on the nature of the bug. Its possible that the bug has nothing to do with the device it its just caused by the way the user is interacting with the app.

Comment: You have to ask what exactly does the client before the bug. Ask them to close all others applications (no background apps), may be a memory warning issue...

Comment: Please describe the bug.

Comment: Ok - I can test it myself on the device. Right now it's a few friends so I can get them to come over. What concerns me is the nature of the bug is not complex. Something like switching views rapidly (which doesn't crash on any of my devices). Or experiencing a crash when unlocking the screen with a push notification (also dones't happen to me). I'm just concerned if these are basic things and not happening in my test enviroment what else am I missing?

Comment: May be programs was build with different options? Xcode build app to device as Debug and to archiving as Release by default. Other way - if programm has a lot of logging, when you run it from Xcode, it spends a lot of time to communicate with Mac. A couple of times I got some more bugs when debug with Xcode cause I could touch more buttons, and I wasn't able to repeat this when launch the same app from ipod without Xcode debugging, in your case it can be revers situation. And if app crashed you can get crash log, its helps you find and fix bug

Comment: Release vs Debug? Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210621/iphone-app-floating-point-calculations-when-released-to-the-app-store

Comment: Release - it happens on the version I am testing via testflight and the one previously released to the app store.